# Suitable loop for output the results of logarithm function in column (C++)

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I have some code in C++ that calculates log2(n) for one entered number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double log(double a, double b) {
    return log(b) / log(a);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << (int)log(2, n);
    return 0;
}
```

How to make it work with n entered numbers. So the input for 5 numbers, for example, must be something like this (each number on self line):

```
5 // Enter amount of numbers below
24958 // Enter the first number
48569 // ... second number...
48564
40506
59232
```

And the output will be:

```
14
15
15
15
15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use array to store numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double log(double a, double b) {
    return log(b) / log(a);
}

int main() {
    int iter, i;

    cin >> iter;
    int arr[iter];

    for ( i=0; i<iter; i++)
       cin >> arr[i];

    for ( i=0; i<iter; i++)
       cout << (int)log(2, arr[i])<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the output for example of 2 numbers will be: `2
24958
14
48569
15`

Comment: Much appreciate! Hm, arrays, I suggested that, but is there any variant without using them? Also now the output is: `1415` for (24958, 48569).

Comment: No, If you want to have output excatly the way you described.

Comment: Add endline character as in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that. Thanks, man, you really help me! And the last maybe stupid question: what do you think about why people voted 'down' for question like that?

Answer (score 0):

Could you show what's actually the code you are using to parse the user input? If you haven't created such code yet, then just do the following:

1. Read the user input and store the first line in a string and convert it to an integer (take a look to  std::getline)
2. Loop as much times as n, and use the getline to read the remaining entries, call your logarithm method and display its output